# how to set textfield width based on it's text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-textinputfield

I want to size the textfield based on text length...while typing it's length should be changed according to text..I was suggested to use IntrinsicWidth but its not working..

```
Container(
              height: 300,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
                      child: IntrinsicWidth(
                        child: TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                          ),

                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.grey[400]),
                              hintText: 'Enter Income Amount'
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: you mean horizontally grow?

Comment: yes....its width.

Comment: Can you include more about parent widget

Comment: Maybe this could help..[FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html)

Comment: its depend on your parent. your code works fine for me.

Comment: I have updated with more code

Comment: @eamirho3ein, it works but what I want is...when I start typing, its length should be as per text length...here it is set minimum length to hint text length...hope got it what I want exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `TextEditingController` instance and call setState to update the UI. I am changing hintText to null based on userInput.

```dart
 final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
 .....

Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
  child: IntrinsicWidth(
    child: TextField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      controller: controller,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {});
      },
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 30,
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey[400]),
        hintText:
            controller.text.isEmpty ? 'Enter Income Amount' : null,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Both are working , the hint text will get initial width

Comment: but when I start typing it's width should be set to length of typed characters...here it  starts with length of hint text

Comment: Inshore,, it fixes minimum width to hint length..that I don't want..it should be based on text length while typing starts

Comment: We can do some trick with controller and calling setState to update ui

Comment: try update answer

Answer (score 1):

Base on what @YeasinSheikh said we can do this on click on the textfield, first define this variable:

```
bool isActive = false;
```

then use it like this:

```
 Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
        child: IntrinsicWidth(
          child: TextField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            controller: controller,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isActive = true;
              });
            },
            onSubmitted: (value) {
              setState(() {
                isActive = false;
              });
            },
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey[400]),
              hintText: isActive ? " " : 'Enter Income Amount',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

or you can wrap your main widget with gesture detecter and make `isActive` false when click on screen.

Comment: my questions are may be baseless, but what I am exactly getting is that...everything is flexible....like the way u applied logic to hint text..Thanks...